# Where does SVN store reposatory files?

Tags: svn, file-storage

What is the default location for reposatory files in SVN? And how does it store them? (plain files,some sort of database)?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There does not exist a default location for the repository. This has to be configured. Either in svnserve or via Apache configuration. Inside the repository the information stored in a compressed form in plain files with a particular structure. This is the FSFS Backend which behaves like a database with transaction and possible rollback. On the other hand there exist the BerkeleyDB backup which uses the BerkeleyDB which was the first backend. But in the meantime the FSFS backup has become to the defacto standard storage. Simpler to backup etc. Details about how the storage is working internally you can find on the [web-site](http://subversion.apache.org)